# Can I split the eth-deposit for running a eth2.0-validator to multiple transactions

Tags: eth-2.0

For running a validator one need to deposit 32ETH to a specific deposit-contract on the ETH1.0 chain. My question is, is it possible to split this deposit to multiple transactions (e.g. 4x8ETH)? Furthermore is this possible from multiple addresses?

From my understanding the validator is bound to the deposit-data which need to be send with the deposit-transaction so I presume that a split is possible but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: How do you actually transfer less than 32? So far I tried with testnet and the transfer fails every time I try to send eth to the address .

Comment: It's been a while since I did this last time but I think it had something to do with the gaslimit if you send via Metamask. Try to increase the limit. I think it has something to do with the checks within the deposit contract. You need more gas for sending less than 32ETH. If I remember correctly. Normally I would try it before answering here but because one is getting no gETH anymore for setting up new validators I can't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is, is it possible to split this deposit to multiple transactions (e.g. 4x8ETH)?

Yes, the smallest deposit you can make is `1 ETH`<sup>1</sup> and you can make as many as you like<sup>2</sup>.

Validators are automatically on-boarded once the sum of their deposits is equal to or greater than `32 ETH`<sup>3</sup>.

> Furthermore is this possible from multiple addresses?

Yes. There are no restrictions regarding sender address in the [Ethereum 2.0 Phase 0 -- Deposit Contract](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/v0.12.0/specs/phase0/deposit-contract.md#vyper-code)<sup>4</sup>.

---

#### References

1. The `1 ETH` deposit amount is enforced on [line 76](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/077577ae8add3068d17b8bc0d67c7398bacae90c/deposit_contract/contracts/validator_registration.vy#L76) in the deposit contract: `assert deposit_amount >= MIN_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT` where `MIN_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT: constant(uint256) = 1000000000  # Gwei`.
2. See the [deposit contract Vyper
   code](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/077577ae8add3068d17b8bc0d67c7398bacae90c/deposit_contract/contracts/validator_registration.vy#L65-L109)
   to see that the contract does not place per-public-key restrictions on deposits. See [process_deposits](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/v0.12.0/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#deposits) to see that the beacon chain does not apply any restrictions to the account balance (apart from being limited to a `u64`, which is inconsequential).
3. It's not trivial to prove that validators are onboarded when they have deposited `>= 32 ETH`, however the [`is_eligible_for_activation`](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/v0.12.0/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#is_eligible_for_activation) function in the spec is a good place to start.
4. See the [deposit contract Vyper
   code](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/077577ae8add3068d17b8bc0d67c7398bacae90c/deposit_contract/contracts/validator_registration.vy#L65-L109)
   to see that the contract does not place per-address restrictions on
   deposits.

Comment: Great info and references. In regards to `1`, I see the assertion. What exactly happens if someone sends < `MIN_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT`. Are the funds lost?

Comment: Thanks :) Sending less than `MIN_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT` will cause the transaction to revert. This will cost some gas/fees, however the `MIN_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT` will not be burned.

Answer (score 0):

I am not on the expert how the staking contract looks like, but with Ethereum you can always use another contract as a sending address and then pool money on this contract first.

Good examples are:

- Multisig wallets (make multiple deposits to e.g. Gnosis Safe wallet and then one single deposit to the staking contract)
- Various pooling contracts

etc.